# White spaces between color tabs and two other questions

Tags: fonts, line-breaking, colortbl

1. **!Partially solved!** How to remove small white spaces between color blocks?  (when you compile this tex there are small white spaces between the `& \cellcolor{EM}\& & \cellcolor{EM}\\`)  [image: white spaces] I found an answer, but I think that this answer is bad: `& \cellcolor{EM}\\[-1pt]
   & & \cellcolor{EM}\\`
2. **!Solved!** What is the best way to use Helvetica in the whole text? (I saw many answers for this question. And I would like to know how to use Helvetica throughout the whole text (what is the best method?)); and this question was answered by Canageek.
3. **!Solved!** And, how to make `\hhline` bigger? I don't want to use `\hhline\hhline` (I want to set the thickness of `\hhline`).

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{tgheros}  
\usepackage{hhline}  
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}  
\usepackage{sectsty}     
\usepackage[usenames]{color}  
\usepackage{colortbl}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\definecolor{EM}{rgb}{0.70,0.86,0.69}      
\begin{document}  
\begin{center}  
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}  
\hline  
day & time & lesson \\  
\hline  
\hline  
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Mon}} & \multirow{2}{*}{$9^{00}-10^{20}$} & \cellcolor{EM}\\  
& & \cellcolor{EM}\\  
\hhline{|~|-|-|}   
\hhline{|~|-|-|}    
& \multirow{2}{*}{$10^{30}-11^{50}$} & \cellcolor{EM} \\  
& & \cellcolor{EM} \\  
\hhline{|-|-|-|}   
\hhline{|-|-|-|}   
\end{tabular}  
\end{center}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: There seems to be more then one question here. Can you edit it to make it clearer what you are asking?

Comment: Now it is better, I think.

Comment: Increasing the rule width for all rules within the `tabular` is possible through `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{<len>}` where you pick `<len>`.

Comment: I want to change ONLY `\hhline` thickness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use `9\textsuperscript{00}--10\textsuperscript{20}` rather than `$9^{00}-10^{20}$` because:

- It's not math.
- It uses the math font rather than the text font.
- `$-$` is a minus sign with its appropriate spacing while `--` is the correct en dash (“9 o'clock to 10.20” not “9 raised to the 0-th power minus 10 raised by the 20-th power”). <sub><sup>`\end{nitpick}`</sup></sub> Compare:
  [image: math vs text]

---

#### White Space

I still believe this is a PDF viewer rendering issue.

When viewing with SumatraPDF at 6400 % (!) I can see the white-ish (they are grey) lines (here at the crossing of the `hhlines`):
[image: SumatraPDF 6400%]

At around 1000 % you can still see them:
[image: Sumatra 1000%]

These are (anti-)aliasing artefacts.
Looking closely at the 6400 % image you can see that there's a lot going on:
[image: 6400% upscaled]

With the Foxit Reader some of these white spaces are not visible at different zoom factors.
Adobe Reader doesn't show them at all (example at 6400 %):

[image: Adobe: 6400%]

Now your `\\[-1pt]` trick does help you in the way, that colored areas do overlap (by `1pt` nonetheless) instead of just touching themselves. *But don't use it; they're really just touching.*
I can also resolve this non-existing issue by (virtually) printing to PDF.

You may have noticed that these thin white spaces are the same size at every zoom factor which is another indicator that this is a rendering issue.

#### Bigger `\hhline`.

Apart from setting a `tabular`-global `\arrayrulewidth` there, as far as I know, are two solutions (meaning one bad solution and one work-around):

- `\hhline{===}` instead of `\hhline{---}`
- New macro `\hhhline` that just expands to two `\hhline`s:

  ```
  \newcommand*\hhhline[1]{\hhline{#1}\hhline{#1}}
  ```

### Or [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)

*The following may not apply to your specific table …*

Instead of using a header which describes the columns in a very [duh!](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duh#Interjection) way <sub><sup>(Really? Mon, Tue, Wed, … do stand for (week)days? Oh, and 9<sup>00</sup>–10<sup>20</sup> is a time (span)?)</sup></sub>, I'd use a combination of `booktabs` and no colors.<sup>†</sup>

Further effort has to be put in the goal of same-width columns (`tabularx`' `X` specification for example). In my own timetable I even have dropped the weekdays headings, because I am (just barely) able to count to five. `;)`

<sup>†</sup> <sub>See [Herbert's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11198/coloring-columns-in-a-table-with-colortbl-and-booktabs#comment19855_11198): “from typographers view it makes no sense to have lines *and* colored cells”, and [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11215/16595).</sub>

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r*5c}
    \toprule
                                                   &           Mon            &     Tue     &   Wed    &  Thu   & Fri \\ \midrule
     9\textsuperscript{00}--10\textsuperscript{20} & \multirow{2}{*}{English} & Mathematics & Deutsch  &  \TeX  & --- \\
    10\textsuperscript{30}--11\textsuperscript{50} &                          &   Physics   & Italiano & \LaTeX & --- \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: booktabs output]

Comment: There will be other people who will use this sched. I wanted to make a better University sched, I'm afraid that some of them will see those white spaces, and it will be really bad. So, only [-1pt] will do the trick?

Comment: `\hhline{===}` prints two lines instead of one.

Comment: Speaking about `\hhline` I fount this solution too:
`\newlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}
\newcommand{\hhhline}[2]{%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\Oldarrayrulewidth}{\arrayrulewidth}}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{#1}}\hhline{#2}%
  \noalign{\global\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\Oldarrayrulewidth}}}` It's bad because it changes width  not only height.

Comment: @Ptech As it is a viewer issue, I'm afraid that only `[-1pt] ` will satisfy you. `\hhline{===}` prints a very thick `hline` in you MWE. And your `\hhhline` solution doesn't change the horizontal dimension but also the width of vertical lines which are drawn in `\hhline`, too.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to use Helvetica in your whole document is, according to [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgheros/)

```
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

TeX Gyre Heros is an extended version of URW Nimbus Sans, which is what you get with the [`helvet` package](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/helvetica/). If you want to keep using the helvet package for whatever reasons, the example loads it as

```
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

I don't know what the differences is between `helvet` and Nimbus Sans (`nimbus`) is, but that is also an option is in `tgheros`:

```
\usepackage{nimbus}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

Sorry I can't help with the rest of your questions, you should really post one question at a time, so that you don't get a mix of answers.

Comment: This was really helpful, TU!