# Cell spacing in table

Tags: tables

Consider the following table.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{,}{#1}}
\newcommand*\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand*\farve[1]{\cellcolor{blue!50}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{d{2.0} d{2.0} d{2.0} d{2.0} d{2.0} d{2.0} d{2.0}}
 \toprule
  \mc{Mandag} & \mc{Tirsdag} & \mc{Onsdag} & \mc{Torsdag} & \mc{Fredag} & \mc{L{\o}rdag} & \mc{S{\o}ndag} \\
 \midrule
              &              &             &              &             &  1             &  2             \\
   3          &         4    &         5   &  6           &  7          &  8             &  9             \\
  10          & \farve{11}   & \farve{12}  & 13           & 14          & 15             & 16             \\
  17          & \farve{18}   & \farve{19}  & 20           & 21          & 22             & 23             \\
  24          &        25    &        26   & 27           & 28          & 29             & 30             \\
  31          &              &             &              &             &                &                \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Question**

How do I color the entire rectangle with the numbers 11, 12, 18, and 19? As can be seen, where is a thin white space between the indiviual cells.

Comment: That's a viewer/rendering issue. Have you tried other viewers or zoomed in?

Comment: I see. When I read the PDF file with Adobe Reader, there is no problem; thank you! (My standard viewer is Evince.)

Comment: Here is a semi-duplicate [LaTeX question about white spaces between color tabs and two small questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79315) on that topic.