# Packages multirow and columncolor give ugly stripes

Tags: beamer, color, multirow

I have two problems on one slide. This is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}

% DEFINE COLORS
\xdefinecolor{lGrey}{RGB}{238,238,238}
\xdefinecolor{dGrey}{RGB}{64,64,64}
\xdefinecolor{myRed}{RGB}{164,30,55}

\title{Example}
\author{PM}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\frame
{
    \frametitle{Title}
    \begin{center}
    {\scriptsize{
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{myRed}}ccc}
        \rowcolor{myRed}
            & \color{lGrey} Metaphor & \color{lGrey} Instrument \\
            \cellcolor{myRed} & Something, & Something else \\
            \cellcolor{myRed}\multirow{-2}{*}{\color{lGrey} My stuff}
                & And more & (and paper and pen) \\
            \cellcolor{myRed} & Hand & Leg, \\
            \cellcolor{myRed}\multirow{-2}{*}{\color{lGrey} Other stuffs}
                & thoughts & data \\
    \end{tabular}
    }}
\end{center}
}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that I am getting ugly stripes for multirow cells: they should be red, but between one can see white line. How can I eliminate this?

Another issue, if I may, is that table is not really centered. It is more to the right.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you add an entire Minimal Working Example (MWE) starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`, in order for us to have the definition of your colors and so on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coloring columns in a table with colortbl and booktabs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11198/coloring-columns-in-a-table-with-colortbl-and-booktabs)

Comment: For the wrong centering, remove the braces `{` before and after `\scriptsize` and also the `}}` before `\end{center}`.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65231/15925 help with eliminating the white lines?

Comment: Unfortunately neither of the above helped! I am still getting ugly stripes! Is it possible that this occurs because I am using my own colors? (I doubt, but I am running out of ideas...)

Comment: This is also a good discussion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79315/latex-question-about-white-spaces-between-color-tabs-and-two-small-questions?lq=1

Comment: This problem may be related with the used pdf-viewer. I can see your problem with Mac Preview, but neither with the build in viewer of texstudio nor Adobe Reader.

Comment: Unfortunately, I managed to solve the issue using some bad approach (coding): \\[-1pt], as commented in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79315/latex-question-about-white-spaces-between-color-tabs-and-two-small-questions?lq=1. However, this seems to be discouraged and not very TeX/LaTeX in spirit... :-(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the white stripes are just a problem with some PDF viewers and pixel rounding