# How to eliminate the gap in a chain?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, nodes, tikz-chains

In the following code, I used `node distance=0` and `outer sep=0` to position the nodes besides each other seamlessly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain=going right,
    every node/.style={on chain, fill=black, text=white},
    text height=.8em,
    text depth=.2em,
    node distance=0,
    outer sep=0pt
  ]
  \node {a};
  \node {bc};
  \node {def};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, the result still shows gaps.

[image: small gaps are still left between the nodes]

What did I miss?

Comment: That's an  artefact of the PDF viewer.

Comment: It’s a rendering issue. See [LaTeX question about white spaces between color tabs and two small questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79315) and [How do I evenly fill the background color of a block of elements inside a TikZ matrix?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137175). I don’t have it in Adobe Reader and Foxit Reader and at some zoom levels in SumatraPDF.

Comment: If you want to cheat, say `node distance=-.1pt` (or `outer sep`) or something like that.

Comment: You can try to add `line width=0pt,draw=black`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It indeed is a problem of the PDF viewer program, not the LaTeX rendering. The document shows with gaps in some viewers, for example

- evince
- zathura
- pdf.js viewer included in Firefox
- Perfect Viewer for Android

and without in others, notably

- the google drive viewer.

---

### Workaround

But still you can use `-\pgflinewidth` as the  `node distance`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain=going right,
    every node/.style={on chain, fill=black, text=white},
    text height=.8em,
    text depth=.2em,
    node distance=-\pgflinewidth,
    outer sep=0pt
  ]
  \node {a};
  \node {bc};
  \node {def};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]