# Table using booktabs and cellcolor looks ugly

Tags: tables, typography, highlighting, booktabs, colortbl

When using `\cellcolor` in a `booktabs` table, I find that the output is not really appealing:

[image: Table]

I don't really care that the colored cell does not touch the lines above and below (cf. [Coloring columns in a table with colortbl and booktabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11198/coloring-columns-in-a-table-with-colortbl-and-booktabs)), but what I find ugly is that the `\cellcolor` command looks bad in combination with the shortened `\midrule` of its header. I was originally going to ask how to simply shorten the `\cellcolor` in a similar way, but I guess the output would still not be very appealing since the `3` would not be centered in its background anymore.

So, here's the more basic question: what is a best practice here to make things look appealing? I do like the `booktabs` style, and I have a few tables in which I'd like to highlight some cells. Note that I'm not dead set on using backgrounds for the highlighting, but I can't think of a better means: using bold seems to communicate that the highlighted values are more important (while in fact they are error cases), using italics they'd be too little obvious.

Here is the corresponding MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{b} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-5}
        1 & 2 & \cellcolor[gray]{0.9}3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is *not trimming* the `\cmidrule`s in question an option for you? For instance, in the example you give, could you live with issuing the commands `\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule{3-5}`, which will trim the first cmidrule on the right and leave the length of the second cmidrule unchanged?

Comment: @Mico: if possible, I'd like to keep the trimming of the mid rules consistent; in the example above, it seems strange to me that `a`'s mid rule would be trimmed while `b`'s would not be.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\cellcolor` adds padding to ensure adjacent cell backgrounds are touching each other. I believe you don't need `\cellcolor` at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ccell}[3][]{%
  \kern-\fboxsep
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\colorbox{#2}}%
  {\colorbox[#1]{#2}}%
  {#3}\kern-\fboxsep
}
\makeatother
\definecolor{cellgray}{gray}{0.9}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\cmidrulekern}{0.3em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{b} \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-5}
1 & 2 & \ccell[gray]{0.9}{3} & 4 & 5 \\
1 & 2 & \ccell{cellgray}{3} & 4 & 5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The two `\kern` commands make TeX thinking the default padding of `\colorbox` has not been added to the cell's width. Changing a bit the amount of trimming from `\cmidrule` ensures the mid rules cover the colored cell.

Note that the syntax of `\ccell` allows for directly specifying a color or also using a defined color.

[image]

The definition of `\ccell` can be simplified into

```
\makeatletter
\protected\def\ccell#1#{%
  \kern-\fboxsep
  \@ccell{#1}%
}
\def\@ccell#1#2#3{%
  \colorbox#1{#2}{#3}%
  \kern-\fboxsep
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the simplicity of this solution. However, this approach "breaks" if some of the cells with background have text of different lengths: the gray background will only cover the text's length, not that of the whole cell. Is there a way to improve that?

Comment: @rainer I'm afraid not.

Comment: Ok, I thought so. Thanks anyway `:)`!

Answer (score 10):

There's also the usual `tikzmark` approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\fillcol}{gray!50}
\newcommand{\bordercol}{white}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
      set fill color/.code={\renewcommand{\fillcol}{#1}},
      set border color/.code={\renewcommand{\bordercol}{#1}},
      left offset/.store in=\leftoff,
      right offset/.store in=\rightoff,
      above offset/.store in=\aboveoff,
      below offset/.store in=\belowoff,
      left offset=-0.02,
      right offset=0.12,
      above offset=0.325,
      below offset=-0.1,
      below right offset/.store in=\belowrightoff,
      below right offset={\rightoff,\belowoff},
      above left offset/.store in=\aboveleftoff,
      above left offset={\leftoff,\aboveoff},
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzmarkin}{o m D(){\belowrightoff} D(){\aboveleftoff}}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%true
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw[line width=1pt,rectangle,fill=\fillcol,draw=\bordercol]
      (pic cs:#2) ++(#3) rectangle (#4)
      ;}
      {%false
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      \draw[line width=1pt,rectangle,fill=\fillcol,draw=\bordercol,#1]
      (pic cs:#2) ++(#3) rectangle (#4)
      ;
      }
}      


\newcommand\tikzmarkend[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2] #1;}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{a} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{b} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-5}
        1 & 2 & \tikzmarkin{a}3\tikzmarkend{a} & 4 & \tikzmarkin[above left offset={0.15,0.325}, below right offset={0.05,-0.1},set fill color=red!80]{b}5\tikzmarkend{b} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Similarly to [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz), there are styles to change width of the highlighted area. One might change `left`, `right`, `above`, `below` `offset`s or the combined `above left`or `below right` `offset`s. An example is given looking on the way in which `5` has been highlighted. Via `offsets` the user has the complete control over the highlighting area size.

The result:

[image]