# Booktabs and colortbl not filling height of row

Tags: tables, booktabs, colortbl

I have a simple booktabs table very similar to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% set the font of the document
\usepackage{fontspec}

% set line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{relsize}

% table materials
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

% define colours
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\definecolor{my-blue}{RGB}{83,87,118}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\rowcolor{my-blue} Variable &  Field One &  Field Two \\
\midrule
A & 0.0002 & 0.0005 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Which produces output like this:

[image]

As can be seen, the row color fill doesn't fill the height of the row, how can this be fixed?

Edit:

In addition is it possible to fix this issue when coloring as single cell such as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% set line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{relsize}

% table materials
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

% define colours
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\definecolor{my-blue}{RGB}{83,87,118}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule 
Variable &  Field One &  Field Two \\
\midrule
\cellcolor{my-blue}{A} & 0.0002 & 0.0005 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To fill the height of the cell?

Answer (score 12):

The space below and above a rule can be filled by a colored rule:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% set the font of the document
%\usepackage{fontspec}

% set line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{relsize}

% table materials
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

% define colours
\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
\definecolor{my-blue}{RGB}{83,87,118}

\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand*{\belowrulesepcolor}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \kern-\belowrulesep
    \begingroup
      \color{#1}%
      \hrule height\belowrulesep
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\aboverulesepcolor}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \color{#1}%
      \hrule height\aboverulesep
    \endgroup
    \kern-\aboverulesep
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\belowrulesepcolor{my-blue}
\rowcolor{my-blue} Variable &  Field One &  Field Two \\
\aboverulesepcolor{my-blue}
\midrule
A & 0.0002 & 0.0005 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you this works. I'm also interested in just colouring one cell using `\cellcolor{}` how would I go about applying this solution to the same problem created using that command? As this applies the color to the whole row and not just a single cell.

Comment: @Ben There is no easy way, because the width and position of the cell is usually not known.

Comment: Is there another way to colour the background of a single cell properly then?

Comment: @Ben Related: [Coloring columns in a table with colortbl and booktabs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11198/16967) or [Table using booktabs and cellcolor looks ugly](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142969/16967)

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` provides tools to color cells, rows and columns in a way compatible with the horizontal rules of `booktabs`. Moreover, you won't see thin white lines, whatever PDF viewer you use.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[colortbl-like]
\toprule
\rowcolor{blue!15} Variable &  Field One &  Field Two \\
\midrule
A & 0.0002 & 0.0005 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

I've used the code of Heiko and had a problem with the usage in the `longtable` environment. [This was my solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294790/how-to-setup-a-longtable-with-booktabs-and-a-colored-head-row). And it works well with the `tabular` environment too.
Hence you should define new lines instead of adding a colored rule:

```
\colorlet{tableheadcolor}{gray!35} % Table header colour = 25% gray
\newcommand{\topline}{\arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{black}}
\newcommand{\midline}{\arrayrulecolor{tableheadcolor}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{black}}
```