# How to remove the space after \midrule in a table

Tags: tables, formatting

I have a table with color in the rows. When the first or last column is colored as shown below, there is an ugly white space before or after the cell. I want to remove this white space (in this picture, it only appears in the first row as it is the colored one. But the same thing applies when the last row is colored. I do not want this space in both the first and last rows).

[image]

Here is the script:

```
%README: this copy with comprehensive attack and defences description.

\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE

  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{colortbl}       
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''} %for qoutation marks

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize\ensuremath{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\maketitle

\begin{table}
\caption{mytable}
\label{table:mytable}

\begin{tabular}{ l *{45}{c} }

  \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5ex]{A}}
    &   AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \midrule
  \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
  Text1 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  Text2 &   \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
  Text3 &   \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
  Text4 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294815/117050

Comment: Isn't this question essentially sacrilege? To answer seems tantamount to apostasy ....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[image]

The spacing can be adjusted using `\aboverulesep = 0.605mm` (adjusts the separation above all kinds of rules except the top one and it has a **default value of 0.4ex or 0.605mm**) and `\belowrulesep = 0.984mm` (adjusts the separation below all kinds of rules except the bottom one and it has a **default value of 0.65ex or 0.984mm**).

If you need to remove the separation frequently you can define `\newcommand{\midsepremove}{\aboverulesep = 0mm \belowrulesep = 0mm}` and `\newcommand{\midsepdefault}{\aboverulesep = 0.605mm \belowrulesep = 0.984mm}` to remove spacing and reset it to the default value. Before `tabular` environment use `\midsepremove` and after it use `\midsepdefault`. This helps reset the spacing to the default values and avoid crowded lines in normal tables.

```
%README: this copy with comprehensive attack and defences description.

\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE

  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{colortbl}       
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

    % The new commands
    \newcommand{\midsepremove}{\aboverulesep = 0mm \belowrulesep = 0mm}
    \midsepremove
    \newcommand{\midsepdefault}{\aboverulesep = 0.605mm \belowrulesep = 0.984mm}
    \midsepdefault

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''} %for qoutation marks

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize\ensuremath{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\maketitle

\begin{table}
\caption{mytable}
\label{table:mytable}
\centering

\midsepremove
\begin{tabular}{ l *{45}{c} }

  \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5ex]{A}}
    &   AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \midrule
  \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
  Text1 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  Text2 &   \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
  Text3 &   \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
  Text4 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\midsepdefault

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Off-topic:** use `\centering` to center the table below the caption. Also, use `\captionsetup{justification=centering}` for better handling of floats caption positions.

Comment: Are you sure your suggestions will be acceptable to the conference or journal to which the OP is submitting?

Comment: Don't use mm for the `\aboverulesep`s. In `\midsepdefault` you should use 0.4ex and 0.65ex for the one below. There is a reason why these are in ex and not in mm or another absolute measurement.

Comment: @cfr Yes, modify columns separation is acceptable if it makes the document more readable. The editor will make the final decisions on how the format will be if the paper is accepted.

Comment: @Skillmon. Why shouldn't we use `mm` here?

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh because `\aboverulesep` is 1.8067pt without your redefinition to 0.605mm and 1.72137pt with it. Well maybe you shouldn't use ex in your command either (because if it's called in a surrounding of different font size, the width is wrong either). You might use mm, but then use the correct value.

Comment: Editors are unlikely to be happy having to pick through and remove things like the addition of `caption` etc. The class is supposed to impose house style. A bunch of modifications undermines that purpose.

Answer (score 14):

You can change `\midrule` by something like `\specialrule{.4pt}{2pt}{0pt}` and the  `\bottomrule` by `\specialrule{.8pt}{0pt}{2pt}`

[image: mwe]

Comment: I think you should use `\heavyrulewidth` for the width of the `\bottomrule` and `\lightrulewidth` for `\midrule` to ensure a uniform look.

Comment: @Skillmon, uhmm...yes,  if you change `\heavyrulewidth` length or you can distinguish 0.8pt of the default (0.80301pt).

Comment: @Fran can you post the modified script please?

Comment: @user6875880 Why? Is just replace both commands in your own example, nothing too tricky.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

With use of `cellspace` package for adding `S` attribute to columns type and settings above and below `booktabs`' rules space to zero:

```
\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace, multirow}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Table title}
    \label{tab:my important table}
\rowcolors{2}{}{gray!20}
\begin{tabular}{ l *{4}{Sc} }
  \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{Sc}{B} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}[1.5pt]{A}}
    &   AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \midrule
  Text1 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  Text2 &   \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
  Text3 &   \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
  Text4 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `tabularx` (for whatever reason), I found this solution useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\newcommand{\midruletop}{\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{0em}}
\newcommand{\midrulebottom}{\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0em}{\belowrulesep}}
\newcommand{\vertsp}{{\Large$\phantom{\mid}$\hspace{-.25em}}}
\newcommand{\hlrow}{\rowcolor{lightgray}\vertsp}
\newcommand{\hlcell}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\vertsp}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabularx}{.5\columnwidth}{XX}
    \toprule
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B}
    \\\midruletop
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\hlcell a}
    \\\midrulebottom
    a & b
    \\\midruletop
    \hlrow a & b
    \\\midrulebottom
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

For highlighting the last line, create a new command from `\midrulebottom` using `\heavyrulewidth`.

Note that the [cellspace manual](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cellspace/cellspace.pdf) suggests that it might also work with `tabularx`. I didn't try, though.

[image]

Comment: There appears to be a white line bw columns. Can that be avoided?

Comment: I suppose that's only due to my PDF renderer. Try rendering it on your own and zoom in and out. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the exact positions of the rules drawn with `booktabs` and to color rows with respect to these rules, you may use `nicematrix`. You need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc}[color-inside]
  \toprule
  \Block{2-1}{A} &  & B & \\
  \cmidrule{2-4} 
  & AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \midrule
  \rowcolors[gray]{0.9}{}
  Text1 & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  Text2 & \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
  Text3 & \xmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
  Text4 & \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution with `booktabs` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: row colors work as expected.

Note that you need to put trim option `lr` into square brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}       
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{mytable}
\label{table:mytable}
\begin{booktabs}{
  colspec = {l*{3}{c}},
  cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{c}, % multirow
  cell{1}{2} = {c=3}{c}, % multicolumn
}
  \toprule
        A &   B      &        &        \\
  \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
          &   AAA    & BBB    & CCC    \\
  \midrule
  \SetRow{gray9}
    Text1 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
    Text2 &   \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
  \SetRow{gray9}
    Text3 &   \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
    Text4 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{booktabs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A small variation of interesting [L.J.R. answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381718/how-to-remove-the-space-after-midrule-in-a-table/614975#614975) (+1), for exercise :-)

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{My table}
\label{table:mytable}
\begin{booktabs}{colspec = {l*{3}{c}},
                 row{odd}={gray9},
                 row{1}={bg=},      <--- a way to define "not colored" row
                }
  \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c} A
            &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} B
                        &        &        \\
  \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}
            &   AAA     & BBB    & CCC    \\
  \midrule
    Text1   &   \cmark  & \cmark & \cmark \\
    Text2   &   \xmark  & \cmark & \xmark \\
    Text3   &   \cmark  & \xmark & \xmark \\
    Text4   &   \cmark  & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{booktabs}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good usage of `bg=`. Better than using `bg=white`.

Comment: And maybe we need an optional argument to `odd` and `even` selectors.  It would be great if we could write `odd[3]` here.

Comment: @L.J.R., yes. I just intent to write a wish on Github, if it is possible to start even/odd coloring of rows at some row. Similarly as it is possible with `rows{<start at row>}{<color 1<}{<color2>} `  as I did in the my first answer (using `[table]{xcolor}` package).

Comment: An optional argument has been added to `odd` and `even` selectors in the source code. In next version 2022A you will be able to write `odd[3]` or `even[2-Y]` for example.

Comment: @L.J.R., thank you for info! When will the 2022A be available?

Comment: See https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/wiki/ChangeLog for the scheduled date and the changes.

Comment: @L.J.R., thank you very much! I'm looking forward to test and use it. Quite  lot of changes!