# Incomplete row table colors

Tags: tables, color, rowcolor

Quick question regarding colouring rows in a latex table:

I simply want to colour the first row in the following table light gray as in the image. Unfortunately the colour does not seem to fill the full row. I think this has something to do with my specification column separation command "\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5cm}".

[image]

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,pra,]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\hspace*{0cm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5cm}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|{5cm}}
        \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\boldsymbol{\text{Some Text}}}\\
        \hline
        a & b & c & d & e & f \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Example...}
        \label{tab:Example}
    \end{table}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the `MWE` as in error free format...

Comment: What is `{5cm}` supposed to do in the list of column specifiers? Probably you wanted something like `p{5cm}` instead?

Comment: You have a `\boldsymbol` outside mathmode.

Comment: Aslo, `\boldsymbol` will only work if used in math mode. Nevertheless, `\boldsymbol{\text{Some Text}}` seems quite unusual. Maybe you wanted `\textbf{some text}` instead?

Comment: @leandriis Yes that's fine. There will be math used I just reduced my tex so that I could show the incomplete row colouring for this post. Do you have an idea of why the colouring is incomplete?

Comment: Please check the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294790/how-to-setup-a-longtable-with-booktabs-and-a-colored-head-row which may suits with your requirement...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've modified the value of `\tabcolsep` inside the figure environment, not in the preamble, so `\rowcolor` (and `\columncolor`) overhang is based on the default value. Workaround: use the optional overhang argument.

Unrelated: needless to load `color` when you load `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,pra,]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\hspace*{0cm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5cm}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|p{5cm}}
        \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}[0.5cm]
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\textbf{Some Text}}\\
        \hline
        a & b & c & d & e & f \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Example...}
        \label{tab:Example}
    \end{table}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you can change the value of `\tabcolsep` anywhere, the command `\rowcolor` will act as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.0}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5cm}
  \begin{NiceTabular}{cccccc}[colortbl-like,hvlines]
  \rowcolor[gray]{0.9}
  \Block{1-*}{\textbf{Some Text}}\\
  a & b & c & d & e & f \\
  \end{NiceTabular}
  \caption{Example...}
  \label{tab:Example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]